# Prove that $333^{555}+555^{333}$ is a multiple of $97$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

What I did so far:

$333^{555}+555^{333} = [(111×3)^{111}]^5+[(111×5)^{111}]^3$

$[(111×3)^{111}]^5+[(111×5)^{111}]^3 = 111^{555}×3^{555}+111^{333}×5^{333}$

I'm stuck.

Comment: It's not true, double check the statement

Comment: 111 is not a multiple of 97. 3^n is also not a multiple of 97

Comment: It is a multiple of 48.

Comment: I get a remainder of $33$ when that number is divided by $97$.

Comment: Probably $97$ should be $37$. Then it's trivially true by $\,37\mid 111\mid 333,555\ \ $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that it's a multiple of $97$ since:

$$\begin{cases}333 \equiv 42 \pmod{97} \\
555 \equiv 70 \pmod{97} \\
333 \equiv 45 \pmod{\varphi({97})} \\
555 \equiv 75 \pmod{\varphi({97})}\end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases}42^{75} \equiv 45 \pmod{97} \\
70^{45} \equiv 85 \pmod{97}\end{cases}$$

$$45+85 \not \equiv 0 \pmod{97}$$

Comment: Better to let the OP correct the problem before posting a counterexample to a typo.

Comment: This is the actual problem on the book, no typos. Thank you for clarifying that.